# Cloudflare Workers Buffer.from()

Tags: javascript, buffer, cloudflare-workers

I am not that familiar with how Buffers and all that work.

In node I can do

```
const str = "dasjkiodjsiodjpasiodfjodifjaspiofjsdioajfpasodfjsdioa";
let buff = Buffer.from(str); // <Buffer 64 61 73 6a 6b 6 etc...
let buffHex = Buffer.from(str, 'hex');

console.log(buff)
```

How would I go about doing this in Cloudflare Workers, because I get `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Buffer` is a Node API. Cloudflare Workers is based on web platform APIs instead, like what you'd find in browsers. The web platform alternative to `Buffer` is `Uint8Array`. You can use the `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder` APIs to convert between `Uint8Array`s with UTF-8 encoding and text strings.

```js
let bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
```

To convert a `Uint8Array` to hex, you can use a function like:

```js
function bytes2hex(bytes) {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(bytes,
      byte => ('0' + byte.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}
```

I do not recommend using a `Buffer` polyfill for this as it'll bloat your code size. It's better to use `Uint8Array` directly.

In general you should be able to find answers about how to do common operations on `Uint8Array` on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Node.js's Buffer API with Cloudflare Workers.

See https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/nodejs/ which explains that by adding `compatibility_flags = [ "nodejs_compat" ]` to your wrangler.toml you can use the following Node.js APIs:

- assert
- AsyncLocalStorage
- Buffer
- EventEmitter
- util

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to create a SHA-256 hash of "hello world" in Cloudflare workers, just using the globally available WebCrypto browser API. Hope it gives you some insight into how this works!

```
export default {
  async fetch(request)
  {
    const myText = new TextEncoder().encode('Hello world!');
    const myDigest = await crypto.subtle.digest({ name: 'SHA-256' }, myText);
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(myDigest));
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
    return new Response(hashHex, {status: 200});
  }
}
```

more info: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/web-crypto/

Answer (score 0):

`Cloudflare` added [Node.js compatibility](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/nodejs/) APIs recently.

If you're using `SvelteKit`, replace your adapter with my [@chientrm/adapter-cloudflare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chientrm/adapter-cloudflare).

In your code:

```
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';
```

Now you can use this `Buffer` object. Example:

```
const bytes = Buffer.from('<some-base64-string>', 'base64');
```